# In Trello, why do some of my boards have a _To Do_, _Doing_, Done_ format and others do not?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

I understand that the default board on Trello has a format using *To Do*, *Doing*, *Done*, but only one of my boards has that template. All the other boards are in three stacks but without the "to do, doing, done" titles. Why is that?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, could you post a screenshot; I'm a little unclear on what you mean by the other boards are in three stacks.